# How to send email in Jenkins with groovy template?

Tags: email, grails, jenkins

I am using Jenkins server for CI and I am trying to send a post-build email using email-ext plugin and groovy template: appsgt.groovy, code below. My default content is empty and my pre send script field is as follows ${SCRIPT, script="managed:appsgt"}.

But I get an error @ line 1 column for column 1: unexpected token <

If I change script to template I still get an error for another line, meanwhile email template testing creates nicely formated data.

```
<STYLE>
BODY, TABLE, TD, TH, P {
  font-family:Verdana,Helvetica,sans serif;
  font-size:11px;
  color:black;
}

</STYLE>
<BODY>
<%
float versionadjust = 103.0f
float newversion = (build.number + 103) / 1000
def realVersion = newversion.round(3)
%>
<TABLE>
  <TR><TD align="right"><IMG SRC="${rooturl}static/e59dfe28/images/32x32/<%= build.result.toString() == 'SUCCESS' ? "blue.gif" : build.result.toString() == 'FAILURE' ? 'red.gif' : 'yellow.gif' %>" />
  </TD><TD valign="center"><B style="font-size: 200%;">BUILD ${build.result}</B></TD></TR>
  <TR><TD>Build URL</TD><TD><A href="${rooturl}${build.url}">${rooturl}${build.url}</A></TD></TR>
  <TR><TD>Project:</TD><TD>${project.name}</TD></TR>
  <TR><TD>Project version:</TD><TD>${realVersion}</TD></TR>
  <TR><TD>Date of build:</TD><TD>${it.timestampString}</TD></TR>
  <TR><TD>Build duration:</TD><TD>${build.durationString}</TD></TR>
</TABLE>
<BR/>

<!-- CHANGE SET -->
<%
def changeSet = build.changeSet
if(changeSet != null) {
    def hadChanges = false %>
    <TABLE width="100%">
    <TR><TD class="bg1" colspan="2"><B>CHANGES</B></TD></TR>
<%  changeSet.each() { cs ->
        hadChanges = true %>        
      <TR>
        <TD colspan="2" class="bg2">&nbsp;&nbsp;Revision <B><%= cs.metaClass.hasProperty('commitId') ? cs.commitId : cs.metaClass.hasProperty('revision') ? cs.revision : 
        cs.metaClass.hasProperty('changeNumber') ? cs.changeNumber : "" %></B> by
          <B><%= cs.author %>: </B>
          <B>(${cs.msgAnnotated})</B>
         </TD>
      </TR>
<%      cs.affectedFiles.each() { p -> %>
        <TR>
          <TD width="10%">&nbsp;&nbsp;${p.editType.name}</TD>
          <TD>${p.path}</TD>
        </TR>
<%      }
    }

    if(!hadChanges) { %>    
        <TR><TD colspan="2">No Changes</TD></TR>
<%  } %>
  </TABLE>
<BR/>
<% } %>


<!-- CONSOLE OUTPUT -->
<% if(build.result==hudson.model.Result.FAILURE) { %>
<TABLE width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<TR><TD class="bg1"><B>CONSOLE OUTPUT</B></TD></TR>
<%  build.getLog(100).each() { line -> %>
    <TR><TD class="console">${org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(line)}</TD></TR>
<%  } %>
</TABLE>
<BR/>
<% } %>

</BODY>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
${SCRIPT, script="managed:appsgt"}
```

^ That should be:

```
${SCRIPT, template="managed.template"}
```

...unless I'm misunderstanding your question.

source: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin#Email-extplugin-Scriptcontent